# Can "that have been" be omitted the same way as "that are"?

Tags: sentence-construction, participles

We can omit **that are** in sentences like:

> "Things **that are** done by our manager are really vital." = "Things done by our manager are really vital."

Now, can I omit **that have been** the same way:

> "Things **that have been** done by our manager over the years are really vital."?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be omitted in the second sentence, if the rest of the sentence carries the change of tense from "that are" to "that have been".

"...over the years..." does that in part, but I would change the last clause to agree with the past tense:

"Things done by our manager over the years *have been* really vital."

Comment: that is to say, both verb tenses should match, shouldn't they?

Comment: You could possibly leave the tense as it was, but it would be odd to say that things are vital now, after having been down over the years.

Comment: I am still confused. I wonder if you would please modify the answer with some examples.